# how to exit set time out in angular if the condition is met

Tags: angular

I have a backend call which with a time:

```js
this.http.get(api)          
   .subscribe(result => {                
      setTimeout(() => {
         if(result["CarStat"=="broken"]){
                
            ///how can stop the timer and exit          
         }
       }, 10000);         
    })
```

as you can see, I need to stop the time once the condition is met, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you use RxJS [`timer`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer) function and [`takeWhile`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile)<sup>(*)</sup> operator

```js
obs$ = timer(0,10000).pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.http.get(api)),
  takeWhile(res => res.CarStart!="broken"),
)
```

you subscribe to `obs$`

```js
obs$.subscribe(res => {
  ..make something with the res..
})
```

<sup>(*)</sup>see that if you want to process the res when `res.CarStart == "broken"` you should use

```js
takeWhile(res => res.CarStart!="broken", true),
```

If only want to execute an action when `res.CarStart=="broken"` the aproach is different, we use [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter)

```js
    obs2$=timer(0,1000).pipe(
        switchMap(_=>this.dataService.getData()),
        filter((result:any)=>result.CarStat=="broken"),
        take(1))
```

Comment: i imported takewhile from rxjs but i get an error No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(predicate: (value: any, index: number) => value is any, inclusive: false):

Comment: see that you should  `import {timer} from 'rxjs'; import {takeWhile,switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'`. A fool stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mmaney?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (I call to this.getData, you should call to this.http.get(api))

Comment: @Eliseo: The `return` statement was missing from the predicates enclosed in the curly braces. I've removed the braces since it's a single statement predicate.

Comment: @mortezasol: I've edited the post to remove the curly braces from the `takeWhile` predicate. Try the solution again.

Comment: @Eliseo thats great example,i have question,in your example you have data(){random} which supplys the ransom number right?in my case should i have such a thing?i only have a api call until the condition is met,and where should pput consle.log to see the final result after the calling ended

Comment: This another stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3sqpzu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts it's more closer that you requeriments. See that it's better to have a service that return the httpClient.get(...) instead write directly in the component. NOTE: If the only you want is execute "something" when `result.CarStat=="broken"` are different. You sould use filter rxjs operator as in the example use the `obs2$`. the "take(1)" is for unsubcribe automaticaty. Really it's looks like complex rxjs, so take a time to understand it

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar situation in one of my angular projects and stopped the timer this way.

```
 this.subscription = interval(5000).subscribe(x => {
 this.subscriptionCount = 1;
 // ...some code goes here....
 });

 if (this.subscriptionCount != 0) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make it clean with `delayWhen` and `interval` operators:

```js
this.http.get(api)  
   .pipe(
      delayWhen((result) => result["CarStat"] == "broken" 
        ? interval(0)
        : interval(10000))
   )        
   .subscribe(result => {                
      ...         
   })
```